# Reshaping a data frame based on column names

Tags: r, list, matrix, split, reshape

I have a data frame consisting of 1 observation and 136 variables. Each variable is a unique combination of different sets, and the observation is a convergence score between each of the two sets. A simplified version of the original df looks like this:

```
#Original df
mydf <- data.frame(setA_setB = c(11), setA_setC = c(21), setB_setC = c(31))
mydf
```

What I am trying to get is a data frame looking like this:

```
#Final df
final.mydf <- data.frame(set = c("setA", "setB", "setC"), setA = c(NA, 11, 21), setB = c(11, NA, 31), setC = c(21, 31, NA))
final.mydf
```

So, it is necessary to first create column and row names splitting the colnames of mydf at "_", and I have been doing this with the following code:

```
#List of set names:
setNames <- unique(unlist(strsplit(colnames(mydf), "_")))
```

Then, I don't know how to proceed in order to assign to each entry of the matrix the correct value based on the column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suggesting the `cast` function from `reshape` package.
We first redefine your dataframe

```
redf <- data.frame(cbind(do.call(rbind,(strsplit(names(mydf),"_"))),t(mydf)),stringsAsFactors = F)
names(redf) <- c("set1","set2","value")
redf
#           set1 set2 value
# setA_setB setA setB    11
# setA_setC setA setC    21
# setB_setC setB setC    31
```

The first two columns are the two sets and the third column is the corresponding value.
Since you want a matrix, which means “two-ways”. We switch the set1 and set2

```
invdf <- subset(redf,set1!=set2)
names(invdf) <- c("set2","set1","value")
invdf
#           set2 set1 value
# setA_setB setA setB    11
# setA_setC setA setC    21
# setB_setC setB setC    31
```

Finally combine the two dataframe and use `cast`

```
alldf <- rbind(redf,invdf)
alldf$value <- as.numeric(alldf$value)
alldf
library(reshape)
cast(alldf,set1~set2,sum)
#   set1 setA setB setC
# 1 setA    0   11   21
# 2 setB   11    0   31
# 3 setC   21   31    0
```

Comment: Thank you very much @TooYoung . Your solution works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
data_frame(key = c(names(mydf), sub("(\\w+)_(\\w+)", "\\2_\\1", names(mydf))), 
        val = rep(unlist(mydf), 2)) %>%
   separate(key, into = c("set", "key2")) %>%
   spread(key2, val)
# A tibble: 3 × 4
#    set  setA  setB  setC
#* <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  setA    NA    11    21
#2  setB    11    NA    31
#3  setC    21    31    NA
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun for your prompt reply. Unfortunately it does not work on my original data frame. I get an error and a warning. The error is **Duplicate identifiers for rows**, and the warning is **Too many values at 62 locations**. I don't understand why, given that the each set combination is unique.

Comment: @Rijak  It says that your duplicate elements whereas in the example it is unique.  Please show a reproducible example

Comment: Sorry. The other solution provided by @TooYoung works fine. I think your solution (which is particularly sleek) does not work because the name of the variables/columns in my original df is not setA_setB as in the example, but are more complex names (without category A, B or C at the end). I guess generalising your code to any type of name separated by "_" would work.